# Web proxy implementation on Java/WebLogic

Tags: java, url, proxy, weblogic

I'm trying to create web application that will implement web proxy.

If you don't know what is web proxy then please see an example of realization http://webproxy.to/

[image]

I have created servlet `web-proxy.do`

Code of servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String proxy = request.getParameter("proxy");
    URL url = new URL(request.getParameter("url"));
    String page = downloadTextFile(url, proxy);

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println(page);
    }
}

private String downloadTextFile(final URL url, final String proxy) throws IOException {
    URLConnection connection = null;
    if (proxy.isEmpty()) {
        connection = url.openConnection();
    } else {
        String host = proxy.replaceAll(":.*", "");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(proxy.replaceAll(".*:", ""));
        SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);

        Proxy theProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, socketAddress);
        connection = url.openConnection(theProxy);
    }

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

Method `downloadTextFile()` does work if it called from Unit test.
Method `downloadTextFile()` does not work if it called from WebLogic server.

For HTTPS `web-proxy.do?url=https://wtfismyip.com&proxy=138.59.205.37:9811` WebLogic return next exception message:

[image]

WebLogic log:

```
<Sep 7, 2020 2:59:18,618 PM BST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101019><[ServletContext@1989240948[app:bc.doc_pragmatic-web-proxy_war_1.0 module:pragmatic-web-proxy-1.0 path:null spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an IOException.
java.net.ProtocolException: unrecognized response from SSL proxy: '
```

For HTTP `web-proxy.do?url=http://wtfismyip.com&proxy=138.59.205.37:9811` WebLogic returns page with single symbol `[`:

[image]

And without proxy `http://localhost:7001/pragmatic-web-proxy/web-proxy.do?url=https://wtfismyip.com&proxy=` it loads page just as expected.

Please let me know if any one have fixed similar issue.

Comment: I used WebLogic 12C, Java 8, EE 7

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the supported TLS ciphersuites at wtfismyip.com. Does proxying for http://wtfismyip.com/ work?